# How to send $file value/path to PHP file using input field and onClick button?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form where I use a GET/IMPORT button to get values from other document and into the current form as shown below. Previously I had set fix value: `$file = '/user/doc.xml';` inside `meta.php` so when I pressed the GET/IMPORT button it got the results from the /user/doc.xml file.

Now I have added `<input name="file" value="" />` to this form and want to send path to $file using this filed. I know when I press GET/IMPORT button then meta.php file is called.

**So my question is**: How can I send $file value/path to meta.php using this input field.

Here is my script and the `$file input field`:

```
<form id=file method="POST"  >
<input name="file" value="" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button').click(function() {
            $.get('meta.php', function(data) {
                result = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("input[name='nick_name']").val(result.avaname);
                $("#age").val(result.tavaage).attr("selected","selected");
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

<input class="button" type="button" value="GET/IMPORT" />
</form>
```

Thank you for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the value from the input field and add it to the querystring of the url. Then in meta.php you can read the filename from the request parameters and load that file.

Don't forget to validate the filename.

```
<input name="file" type="text" id="file">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button').click(function() {
            var val = $('#file').val();

            $.get('meta.php', {file: val}, function(data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('input[name="nick_name"]').val(result.avaname);
                $('#age').val(result.tavaage).attr('selected', 'selected');
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="button" class="button" value="GET/IMPORT">
```

Then in your `meta.php` you can get the the filename with `$_GET['file']`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry I was doing something wrong there with `$_GET` request. Now I tried again and its WORKINGGG :D :D Thanks a MILLION man!! Exactly what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method with "data" like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
         $.get('meta.php', {file: $('input[name="file"]').val()}; function(data) {
             result = $.parseJSON(data);
             $("input[name='nick_name']").val(result.avaname);
             $("#age").val(result.tavaage).attr("selected","selected");
         });
     });
 });
```